# asp.net rendering a line chart

Tags: asp.net, charts, line

I have been trying to render a line chart using the basic asp.net Chart class. Whatever I do, it always renders a column chart.
Here is my code where I am binding a datatable to the chart.

```
var IEtable = (table as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();

var chart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 1000)
    .AddSeries(chartType: "Line").AddLegend("Key")
    .AddTitle("Time Series Metric")
    .DataBindCrossTable(IEtable, "Key", "Date", "Value");
```

Can anyone please help? I am been breaking my head with this thing since more than 12 hours now.

Comment: Looks like someone deleted my last question. Maybe due to the previous arguments. I'll post it again in case anyone has an idea.

Comment: lot of links that have examples of line charts are basically setting the charttype to line. I have tried doing that as well like in my code above. But it didnt help. Is there a way to work around this? Or I'm starting to wonder if asp.net has a constraint that it only renders a column chart when you bind a datatable to a chart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building my charts slightly differently - perhaps because I'm building mine in MVC pages?
Anyway, I'm still using the MS Chart stuff - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410579.ASPX

I create my chart:

```
var chart = new Chart();
chart.Width = 900;
chart.Height = 500;
...lots more options...
```

then add my series one at a time....

```
chart.Series.Add(CreateDataSeries(id, "GI Lower", null, null, GetGILowerDataPoints));
chart.Series.Add(CreateDataSeries(id, "GI Upper", null, null, GetGIUpperDataPoints));
```

where CreateDataSeries sets the chart type like this:

```
Series seriesDetail = new Series();
seriesDetail.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
...
return seriesDetail;
```

Does that help at all?